# Objective c WebKit on Mac OS X outputs HTTPHeader logs

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview, webkit

I have a project that has been written by other programmer and it uses WebKit. 
The problem is that, the `Webview` prints some default logs like this

```
{
  "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, no-store";
  "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
  "Content-Length" = 218;
  "Content-Type" = "text/xml";
  Date = "Thu, 13 Mar 2014 13:14:46 GMT";
  Expires = "-1";
  "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=3, max=993";
  Pragma = "no-cache";
  Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
  Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
  "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
}
```

And I cannot disable these logs.

I made deep search in google, there is not an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your codebase search for [NSLog](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSLog) statements.

(from Xcode use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> to invoke *Search All Files*)